# polynomial rings in two variables

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, ideals

Why  are not the rings $F[x,y]/(y^2-x)$ and $F[x,y]/(y^2-x^2)$ isomorphic? (Where $F$ is an arbitrary field)

Roughly speaking, I realize that $F[x,y]/(y^2 -x)$ "behaves" as $F[y]$ while $F[x,y]/(y^2 -x^2)$ "behaves" as $F[y] \oplus xF[y]$, but how can I prove that with a formal argument?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the unique homomorphism from $F[y]$ to $F[x, y]/(y^2-x)$ that sends $y$ to the equivalence class $[y]$ is an isomorphism. So, as you say, $F[x, y]/(y^2-x)$ "behaves" exactly like $F[y]$ and, in particular, it is an integral domain. But, in $F[x, y]/(y^2-x^2)$, the elements $[x + y]$ and $[x - y]$ are non-zero (because the ideal $(y^2 - x^2)$ doesn't contain any polynomials of total degree less than $2$) and $[x + y]\cdot[x - y] = [(x + y)\cdot(x - y)] = [x^2 - y^2]= 0$, so $F[x, y]/(y^2-x^2)$ has non-trivial zero divisors and is not an integral domain.

Comment: What is the unique mapping that you mention in your first sentence?

Comment: The inclusion composed with the projection?

Comment: I should have said "homomorphism" rather than just "mapping" (I have now). It's the one that is given by the universal property of polynomial rings. See  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_ring. It does amount to the inclusion followed by the projection in this case.

Comment: I don't understand how you apply the UP. Could you elaborate please? Sorry for being slow.

Comment: The universal property for $F[y]$ says that for any $F$-algebra $R$ and any element $z$ of $R$, there is a unique $F$-algebra homomorphism from $F[y]$ to $R$ that maps $y$ to $z$. (The Wikipedia page talks about rings containing a field $K$ rather than $K$-algebras, but these notions are equivalent for present purposes.)